# Input text doesn't show keyboard on iOS simulator

Tags: keyboard, react-native, ios-simulator

I'm building an app and I need to use an input text.

The problem comes when you tap on this input text, the keyboard doesn't appear.

I don't know why, I don't know what I'm doing wrong. It is supposed to be straightforward.

Here is some of my code:

```
<View style={ styles.storyContentContainer }>
    <TextInput ref='username' style={{width: 300, height: 20, borderWidth: 1,}}/>
</View>
```

And a video to show to you guys when the input text gets the focus nothing happen:

[image]

I hope you guys can help me with this issue.

Answer (score 263, accepted):

I assume you are running this on the iOS simulator? Turn off the host machine's hardware keyboard integration by unchecking `Hardware > Keyboard > Connect Hardware Keyboard`, or you can use the Keyboard Shortcut: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, and the keyboard will appear when you focus on a `TextInput`.

You can also manually toggle the software keyboard visibility with <kbd>Cmd</kbd> +<kbd>K</kbd>.

On a real device the keyboard should work out-of-the-box as expected.

Answer (score 22):

Here is how you can easily disconnect your hardware key board.
Now when you will focus inside textInput area, it will open the keypad of iOS simulator
[image: Image shows how to disconnect your hardware keyboard from iOS simulator]

Comment: Toggle Software Keyboard worked for me !!

Comment: this was quick. I was thinking it might be some serious input issue :p

Answer (score 7):

If the keyboard is not popping on click of `TextInput` then just tap on the iOS simulator and press cmd + k.
After that, it will be showing every time you tap on the `TextInput`.